# Get element by dynamic Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute a function on mousedown and mouseup events.

```
$("body").mousedown(function (e1){
highlight_div= e1.target.id

});

$("#"+ highlight_div).mouseup(function (e2){ 
  //do some stuff
 });
```

mouseup event function is not getting executed. If I replace it with actual id , it works.

Comment: Use a non-dynamic class instead. Otherwise, further explain why you need this, because `highlight_div` will not have a value until the mousedown happens, which is well after both bindings are being created

Comment: i am getting data from database, and I cannot change that. The elements only have ids. I need to execute the same stuff inside mouseup function for different divs with different ids

Comment: This will fail for all elements on page that aren't the ones you want and don't have an id. Provide a [mcve] and suggest targeting those elements by class name

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document.body).mousedown(function (e1){
  if (e1.target.id) {
    $(el1.target).addClass('active');
  }
});

$(document.body).on('mouseup', '.active', function (e2){ 
  $(e2.target).removeClass('active');
  //do some stuff
});
```

Add a class to the element on mousedown.  Then use a delegate to handle the mouse up of the active element.